# Why is an answer deleted without an explanation

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

I have a question about my Super User post: [Would this ssh configuration allow host1 to access host3?](https://superuser.com/questions/1701389/would-this-ssh-configuration-allow-host1-to-access-host3/1701425#1701425)

There is probably a good reason that my answer on this question has been deleted but I do not understand why. I like to know this in order to avoid that I spend time in answering a question that is going to be deleted.

I read the page that explain why certain answers are deleted but I did not see a criteria that explains why my answer has been deleted.

I don't mind that answers are deleted but it would be nice if an explanation would be given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was flagged by a community user and a moderator (me) deleted it as it was little more than a comment of "yes it should".

We prefer answers to provide context and per [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) we prefer you to say *why* it should work rather than just "yes".

> Answer the question
>
> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Admittedly you do at least add "I tried it" as well, so I have undeleted it for now, but it could really do with some more supporting background on *how to make it work in practice*.